# How to use Backbone.Router with URL's, containing spaces or round brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, marionette

Default Backbone.Router implementation working incorrect, for example this URL is not handled by the router:
http://localhost:8080/cmp/campaigns/20416/files/wondertag10(1).xls/info

But this URL is working correct:
http://localhost:8080/cmp/campaigns/20416/files/wondertag10.xls/info

---

Router code:

```
var fileInfo = function (id, filename) {
    App.screenBody.show(App.CMP.FileInfo.Main.get({
        id: id,
        fileName: filename
    }));
};

'cmp/campaigns/:id/files/:filename/info': 'fileInfo'
```

---

I think, this is due to a regular expression that uses the backbone library. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use regular expressions within the router object but you can set them in the initialize function of the router e.g.:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.route(/cmp\/campaigns\/(\d+)\/files\/([a-z(\d+)]+(.*))\/info/, 'search');
}
```

The regex in the above route definition will take any numerical characters and the second will take a string which begins with characters, contains a number surrounded by parenthesis and ends with any other characters. This will result in both filenames with and without parenthesis present.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/wwo2s90k/).